# Print Singly linked list in reverse using recursion - Java

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

Hi I am having a little trouble trying to print a singly linked list in reverse order using recursion. I have looked at some examples but my method doesn't take any parameters. I want to print it out in the following format:

```
input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and output:[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

first refers to to first node in my singly linked list and I use `StringBuilder` to build up my list so I can return it at the end.

This is what I have so far:

```
public String printReverse() {
    StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder("[");
    if (head != null) { // base case
        head = head.next;
        myString.append(head.value);   // line 406
        myString.append(", ");         // line 407
        printReverse();                // line 408
    }
    myString = myString.append("]");
    return myString.toString();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myprog.SLL$Node.access$100(SLL.java:445)

    at myprog.SLL.printReverse(SLL.java:406)

    at myprog.SLL.printReverse(SLL.java:408)

    at myprog.SLL.printReverse(SLL.java:408)

    at myprog.SLL.printReverse(SLL.java:408)

    at myprog.SLL.printReverse(SLL.java:408)

    at myprog.SLLApp.myMethod(SLLApp.java:198)

    at myprog.SLLApp.<init>(SLLApp.java:37)

    at myprog.SLLApp.main(SLLApp.java:26)
```

I don't see what I am doing wrong, but I suspect it may be the way I call the method on itself. Can anyone suggest what I may be doing wrong and how I may go about fixing it?

Thanks!

Comment: When you do `head = head.next;` you should check to make sure `head` is not the last node in the list. Otherwise `head` will be `null` and thus you get `null pointer exception`.

Comment: `if (head.next != null)` should be condition

Comment: Your comment `// base case` is misleading, since the block inside `head != null` is exactly the opposite (i.e., the recursive case).

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder I tried it like you suggested but now I get [4, ]
as the output. Is my printReverse() call right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are over complicating things. Lets look at the pseudo code:

- initial node is head
- if next is null print blank (recursion termination condition)
- else recurse to next node
- then print current node

In code, this becomes:

```
public String printReverse() {
    return printReverse(head); 
}

private String printReverse(Node n) {
    return next == null ? "" : (printReverse(next) + n.value);
}
```

It's really only two lines of code - see [KISS](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Regarding the second private method, it is very common for the public method of a recursive implementation to just set ip the call to a private recursive method with the appropriate initial state.

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. I tried it it out. I don't have a variable next and assuming you meant the one that points to the element after head, I tried it with head.next in the conditional and got a StackOverflowError for that line. Any suggestions?

Sorry for all the questions. I'm not that experienced. Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: I was guessing. Post you node class please, so I know how you've set it up.

Comment: Hi thats ok i think I figured it out how to do it. I just used it how u said and changed it a little more

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare the result variable inside the method. You can have it as parameter to a private helper method though. Here is a sample implementation:

```
public String printReverse(Elem elem) {
    return internalReverse(elem, new StringBuilder("[")).append("]").toString();
}
private StringBuilder internalReverse(Elem elem, StringBuilder result) {
    if (elem != null) { // base case
        result.append(internalReverse(elem.next, result));                
        if (result.size() > 1) {
            result.append(", ")
        }            
        result.append(elem);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Javascript solution.

```
function printReverse(list) {
    if (!list) return;
    if (list.next) {
        printReverse(list.next);  
    }
    console.log(list.value);
}
```

Comment: we are talking about the linkelist not a list